# Selecting end date in datepicker deletes previously saved start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm having a strange problem with a datepicker in which I'm constraining start and end dates against each other.

The dates refer to the start and end dates of a medication. The problem comes when I go to edit a medication record that has a start date but no end date. When I click the end date datepicker and select a date, the start date field gets deleted.

This doesn't happen when initially creating the record, only upon editing a previously saved record. I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's the datepicker code that constrains the dates:

```
function attachDatepickers() {
    $('.medication_ended_at input').datepicker().change( function() {
            var selected_date = $('.medication_ended_at input').datepicker('getDate');
            var ended_at = new Date( Date.parse( selected_date ) );
            ended_at.setDate( ended_at.getDate() - 1 );
            var maxStartDate = ended_at.toDateString();
            maxStartDate = new Date( Date.parse( maxStartDate ) );
            $('.medication_started_at input').datepicker("option","maxDate",maxStartDate);
        });

    $('.medication_started_at input').datepicker().change( function() {
            var selected_date = $('.medication_started_at input').datepicker('getDate');
            var started_at = new Date( Date.parse( selected_date ) );
            started_at.setDate( started_at.getDate() + 1 );
            var minEndDate = started_at.toDateString();
            minEndDate = new Date( Date.parse( minEndDate ) );
            $('.medication_ended_at input').datepicker("option","minDate",minEndDate);
        });
}
```

Let me know if need any additional context.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I believe that fiddle demonstrates part of the problem! Take a closer look, its not quite working. When the datepickers are first set up, they're unaware of their own content. You can see that the end date isn't constrained by the prefilled start date. Thanks, this gives me something to work with.

Comment: And what about triggering change event when creating the event handler [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8e81f9wo/1/)